# Inno setup browse for directory to copy/move to new directory

Tags: inno-setup

**Scenario**

User can browse for a directory on the computer. The directory files and sub directory will be copied to the installation location
Also check if a file (myprogram.exe) exist in this folder otherwise do not allow the directory files/sub directory to be moved

Need this so, users that have the program before this installer was made can just select the folder where its currently located and can be moved to program files for future program updates.

How can I do this in Inno Setup?

Comment: So you want another "select directory" page and have the selected directory be copied to the new installation directory (selected on the standard "select directory" page)? Before an installation starts? Or is this all that the installer will do?

Comment: Yes i want other "select directory" page before the installation starts

Comment: So what part of the task do you have a problem with? The page or the copying?

Comment: im fine with the page just don't know how to to the copying part. Can't find any documentation on it